# How to display a long list view with images without run out of memory?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-bitmap

I'm developing an app that display a listview with different images that are edited when the user click on them.

This is the code of my row.xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
     android:text="TextView" 
     android:textSize="25sp"


     />
```

I'm using only one set of images, stored in the folder res/drawable/drawable-nodpi (Because I need them to keep its original size in order to edit them as bitmaps).

The problem is that those images are to big too be displayed in a single activity and therefore, when I create the listview it use a lot of memory and the list is scrolls with some lag. How can I display those images in the list without this problem? Should I create another set of smaller images to use them in the list? I've read post when the app save the images to the SD card, or the cache memory, but actually i'm not sure about the solution that fit best with my specific application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Universal Image Loader class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link below to make your list. Here they free the image cache once it is not seen. Using this you can put many image sin your list :

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
Android-Universal-Image-Loader libriary. This project aims to provide a reusable instrument for asynchronous image loading, caching and displaying. It is originally based on Fedor Vlasov's project and has been vastly refactored and improved since then.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

and for drawable resources  use this..

**String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)**

Answer (score 0):

I think these ways may help:

1. Put these images in server, then use Universal image loader to load it. Universal image loader have solved this problem. you can try this project https://github.com/dodola/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
2. If you have to put these images in res, I think you can implement you own image loader. In  your Image loader, you have to cache the images in memory by use softreference. This is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Aquery to download images. Just download the jarfile from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query.0.26.7.jar)

**How to use :**

```
AQuery _aq = new AQuery(youractivity context);

//fetch and set the image from internet, cache with file and memory 
aq.id(R.id.your_imageview_object).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```